# Change product price on all pages by using observer Magento

Tags: magento, events, observers

I am learning Magento and I have start learning events and observers. A percentage of amount is added to product by setting in admin product area.
It works fine but the discounted price shows only on product page. Can anybody suggest me how can I change the price through out Magento. I mean change price should go to cart, order etc.

Below is the code for **observer**

```
<?php
class Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Applies the special price percentage discount
     * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return  Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer
     */
    public function apply_discount_percent($observer)
    {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $product = $event->getProduct();   
      // process percentage discounts only for simple products     
      if ($product->getSuperProduct() && $product->getSuperProduct()->isConfigurable()) {
      } else {
        $percentDiscount = $product->getPercentDiscount();

        if (is_numeric($percentDiscount)) {
          $today = floor(time()/86400)*86400;
          $from = floor(strtotime($product->getSpecialFromDate())/86400)*86400;
          $to = floor(strtotime($product->getSpecialToDate())/86400)*86400;

          if ($product->getSpecialFromDate() && $today < $from) {
          } elseif ($product->getSpecialToDate() && $today > $to) {
          } else {
            $price = $product->getPrice();
            $finalPriceNow = $product->getData('final_price');

            $specialPrice = $price - $price * $percentDiscount / 100;

            // if special price is negative - negate the discount - this may be a mistake in data
            if ($specialPrice < 0)
              $specialPrice = $finalPriceNow;

            if ($specialPrice < $finalPriceNow)
              $product->setFinalPrice($specialPrice); // set the product final price
          }
        }   
      }         
      return $this;
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <xyzcatalog>
             <class>Xyz_Catalog_Model</class>
        </xyzcatalog>
    </models>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_get_final_price>
        <observers>
          <xyz_catalog_price_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer</class>
            <method>apply_discount_percent</method>
          </xyz_catalog_price_observer>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_get_final_price>     
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Please advise how I can use the new discounted price throughout Magento. Thanks

Comment: Is my answer helpful to solve your problem? Have you fixed it?

Comment: @dushyant  if i feel the issue is solved only than i can accept

Answer (score 6):

Here is solution

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Seta_DiscountPrice>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Seta_DiscountPrice>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <setadiscountprice>
                <class>Seta_DiscountPrice_Model</class>
            </setadiscountprice>
        </models>
        <events>
        <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <seta_discountprice_price_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Seta_DiscountPrice_Model_Price_Observer</class>
                    <method>apply_10</method>
                </seta_discountprice_price_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <seta_discountprice_price_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Seta_DiscountPrice_Model_Price_Observer</class>
                        <method>apply_view</method>
                    </seta_discountprice_price_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Seta_DiscountPrice_Model_Price_Observer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Applies the special price percentage discount
     * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return  Seta_DiscountPrice_Model_Price_Observer
     */
public function apply_10($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();
    // process percentage discounts only for simple products
    if ($product->getSuperProduct() && $product->getSuperProduct()->isConfigurable()) {
    } else {

        $product->setFinalPrice(10);
    }
    return $this;
}
    public function apply_view($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $myCustomPrice = 10;
        $products = $observer->getCollection();

        foreach( $products as $product )
        {
            $product->setPrice( $myCustomPrice );
            $product->setFinalPrice( $myCustomPrice );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've literally saved me so much time with this answer!

Comment: This for all product can we do for specially selected product?

Comment: Yes. This solution will apply for simple products. You can see my comment above the code "process percentage discounts only for simple products" I only set with simple product.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why not using 'catalog price rules' or 'special price' function of products? These are inbuilt functions to do this kind of stuff.
2. For add to cart price change, you need another event to observe. Crash course:

You have to build an observer that catches the add-to-cart event `sales_quote_add_item` and then you can do the php-stuff in the observer like you did on the product page to change the price for the product added to card with:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->setOriginalCustomPrice([your price])
```

Comment: Re: option 1, if the price modification involves decimal precision > 4, this is not possible as MySQL field types for prices are set to `DECIMAL(12,4)`

Answer (score -1):

Exactly for this task it's better to use `Catalog Price Rules` from `Promotions` menu.

But as I understand you are making this with learning purposes. So when you are not sure for an event you could just log the dispatched events. In `app/Mage.php` you have a method called `dispatchEvent`. Then you could just log every dispatched event:

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    if(strpos($name, 'product') || strpos($name, 'price')) { // optional
        Mage::log($name, null, 'events.log', true);
    }
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

Your log file will be created in `var/log` folder. Of course don't forget to revert `Mage.php` to it's original version when you're done. It's not a good idea to change core files.